# XML Schema: choice and minOccurs

Tags: xsd

In this example below,

```
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Start"/>
            <xs:element ref="Center"/>
            <xs:element ref="End"/>
            <xs:element ref="PI" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="Feature" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
```

What happens when choice has minOccurs > 1? Does this mean element "Start" can occur 3 times?

Comment: +1 for unique and valid question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What happens when choice has minOccurs > 1? Does this mean element "Start" can occur 3 times?

**Yes `<Start>` can occur 3 or more times!** Having minOccurs of choice as more than 1 allows set of elements to appear more than once or different elements appear multiple times.

***Detailed explanation:*** 
In the above example you have applied minOccurs as 3 for `<Choice>` and maxOccurs as unbounded! That means .. Child elements listed under `<Choice>`, any three of them or any tag repeated three times should appear under their parent! sample XML are listed below:

Let us assume that these set of tags appear under a node called `<parent>` then:

```
  <parent>
    <Start>Start1</Start>
    <Center>Center1</Center>
    <End>End1</End>
  </parent>
```

-------- OR --------

```
  <parent>
    <Center>Start1</Center>
    <Center>Center1</Center>
    <Feature>End1</Feature>
  </parent>
```

-------- OR --------

```
 <parent>
    <Start>Start1</Start>
    <Start>Start1</Start>
    <Start>Start1</Start>
    <Start>Start1</Start>
  </parent>
```

all the above combinations are valid!

**BUT** you have also defined minOccurs="0" for 'PI' and 'Feature' ..

**This addition causes Validator to pass parent with no child elements as well.** ie:

```
  <parent>
  </parent>
```

If you remove minOccurs from those two elements then validation forces you to include minimum of 3 tags to be included under parent.

Also having `maxOccurs="unbounded"` for `Feature` Element is of no use! The behavior won't change if you add it or take it off..

Comment: What if you want to allow the child elements (if they appear) to only appear once?

Comment: @peco, edit this in the schema in the question: `<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">`. 0 or 1 child can appear

Comment: But then only one child can occur right? Not `<Start> <Center>` and `<End>`. I want atleast one of them to be picked.

Comment: @peco, I don't want to update this answer. I'll post a new q and answer. Will share the link here..

Comment: InfantPro'Aravind',  I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780062/xsd-choice-with-atleast-one-complextype

Answer (score 4):

In readable regexp-like syntax rather than verbose masses of pointy brackets, you have

(Start | Center | End | PI? | Feature*){3,}

which means anything inside the parentheses 3 or more times, and it need not be the same item each time.  Given that there are nullable alternatives - PI? and Feature* - among the choices, the entire expression is also nullable, which means that any number of nulls, including zero, would satisfy the constraints too.

To answer your specific question, yes, 'Start' can occur three (or more times).  It can occur any number of times, as a matter of fact.