# No repeat elements among child elements?

Tags: xml, xsd

Imagine I have the following complex types:

```
<xs:complexType name="pet">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="add" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="pets">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="dogs" type="pet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="cats" type="pet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="hamsters" type="pet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="horses" type="pet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This means that I can specify my xml like this:

```
<pets>
    <dogs>
        <add>Fido</add>
        <add>Pluto</add>
    </dogs>
    <cats>
        <add>Zorro</add>
        <add>Batman</add>
    </cats>
    <hamsters>
        <add>Bob</add>
    </hamsters>
    <horses>
        <add>Mr Horse</add>
    </horses>
</pets>
```

But what I really would like to do is to have my schema demand that at least one of the `pet` types are defined. If I change my `pets` type to:

```
<xs:complexType name="pets">
    <xs:choice  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="dogs" type="pet" />
        <xs:element name="cats" type="pet" />
        <xs:element name="hamsters" type="pet" />
        <xs:element name="horses" type="pet" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

This sort of makes it work because it is now demanded that I have at least one `pet` defined. However, it is now valid to have multiple `pet` elements of the same type. This is what I want to avoid. The following is now valid:

```
<pets>
    <dogs>
        <add>Pluto</add>
    </dogs>
    <dogs>
        <add>Fido</add>
    </dogs>
</pets>
```

So, is it possible to only accept one `pet` element per type?

Comment: After thinking this back and forth, the only solution I could come up with is spelling out all possible first elements and then allow it be followed by zero or one instances of the remaining elements in arbitrary order. I'm not happy with this solution but it seems doable if there is no better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Along the lines [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780062/xsd-choice-with-atleast-one-complextype#comment59232962_35780062) by @5gon12eder:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="pets">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="dogs" type="pet"/>
          <xs:element name="cats" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="hamsters" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="horses" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="cats" type="pet"/>
          <xs:element name="dogs" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="hamsters" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="horses" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="hamsters" type="pet"/>
          <xs:element name="dogs" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="cats" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="horses" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="horses" type="pet"/>
          <xs:element name="dogs" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="cats" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xs:element name="hamsters" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="pet">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="add" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### XSD 1.1

Using `xs:assert` to ensure that there is at least one child of `pets`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="pets">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="dogs" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="cats" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="hamsters" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="horses" type="pet" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="*"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="pet">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="add" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This gets the job done alright, although the 1.0 version is not the prettiest :I Thanks!